# Find character in a string

Tags: c++

I cant get the char search to work. The substring function is working but the char search won't provide the right location of the char it is looking for

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int charsearch(string searchInto, char ch, int start = 0)
{
    int x = 0;
    long n = searchInto.length();
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << ch;
        if (searchInto[i] == ch)
        {    
            i = x;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    cout<< x;
    return x;
}

int substr(string src, string tosearch, int start = 0)
{    
    string searchInto = src;
    long n = searchInto.size();
    long m = tosearch.size();
    int ans = -1;

    for (int i = start; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int p = i;
        int q = 0;
        bool escape = false;
        while (p < n && q < m) {
            if (searchInto[p] == tosearch[q]) {
                if (tosearch[q] == '/' && !escape) {
                    ++q;
                } else {
                    ++p; ++q;
                }
                escape = false;
            } else if (!escape && tosearch[q] == '*') {
                ++q;
                while (q < m && p < n && searchInto[p] != tosearch[q])    ++p;
                escape = false;
            } else if (!escape && tosearch[q] == '?') {
                ++p; ++q;
                escape = false;
            } else if (tosearch[q] == '/' && !escape) {
                escape = true;
                ++q;
            } else break;
        }

        if (q == m) {
            return i;
        }

        if (q == m - 1 && tosearch[q] == '*') {
            if (q > 0 && tosearch[q - 1] == '/') continue;
            else return i;
        }
    }
    return ans;

}

int main()
{
    string searchInto, tosearch;
    cout<< "Enter string:";
    getline(cin, searchInto);
    cout << "Looking for :";
    getline(cin, tosearch);
    if (tosearch.length() < 2)
    {
        char ch = tosearch.at(0);
        cout << "Found at: " <<charsearch(searchInto, ch) << endl;
        cout << "Used Char" << endl;
    }
       else
        cout << "Found at: " <<substr(searchInto, tosearch) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that your implementation of search ignores start parameter

Answer (score 2):

To find a character in a string, you have two interfaces.

1. `std::string::find` will return the position of a character you find:

   ```
   auto pos = yourStr.find('h');
   char myChar = yourStr[pos];
   ```

If the character does not exist, then `std::string::npos` will be returned as the `std::size_t` returned for position.

2. `stl algorithm` `std::find`, in header `algorithm` returns an iterator:

   ```
   auto it = std::find(yourStr.begin(), yourStr.end(), 'h');
   char myChar = *it;
   ```

If the character does not exist, then `it == yourStr.end()`.

Comment: Would also be useful to mention what happens when there is no such item present in a string. `std::string::find` will return `std::string::npos` and `std::find` will return `yourStr.end()`. It should be mandatory to check for one of these two before using the result, for example as `char myChar = yourStr[pos]`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some silly mistakes in your `CharSearch` method. First of all, You have to break the loop when you got your target character. And most importantly you are not assigning `x` when you are finding the target. Furthermore, there is extra increment of value i inside the loop. I have modified the function. Please check it below

```
int charsearch(string searchInto, char ch, int start = 0) {

    int x = -1;
    long n = searchInto.length();
    for (int i = start; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << ch;
        if (searchInto[i] == ch)
        {

           x = i; // previously written as i = x which is wrong
           break; // loop should break when you find the target
        }
     }

     cout<< x;
     return x;
}
```

Please note that,you can either also use `find` method of `string` or `std::find` of `algorithm` to search in string.

Comment: The loop should be starting at the requested `start` index. And `x` needs to be initialized with -1 instead of 0 in case no match is found.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make changes as per this code

```
int charsearch(string searchInto, char ch, int start = 0)
{
    int x = -1; // : change,  if return -1, means not found 
    long n = searchInto.length();
    for (int i = start; i < n; i++) // : change
    {
        cout << ch;
        if (searchInto[i] == ch)
        {
            x = i; // : change
            break; // : change
        }
    }
    cout<< x;
    return x;
}
```

Note : This function will return 1st match.